# Date object throwing invalid date with timezones

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code like below, which produces an invalid `Date`.

```
var pickedUpDate = new Date(val + 'T13:00:00');
```

I am not sure what this piece of code does with `'T13:00:00'`. 
The `val` i am passing is like `"11/11/2222"`.

In the later stage, i am using it like below:

```
if (pickedUpDate < currentDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)) {

}
```

Comment: The date string you're building is not valid, and that's what the error is telling you. Date parsing in JavaScript is tricky and you're really better off using something like momentjs that'll allow you to explicitly describe your date format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an ISO date with a format like 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss' so you should set your val to something like `2017-12-30` so that it gives `2017-12-30T13:00:00`.